# "object 'day' not found r". But 'day' is a column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm studying the main functions of `dplyr` package. When I type `flights` I have it:

```
year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay
   <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>
1   2013     1     1      517            515         2
2   2013     1     1      533            529         4
3   2013     1     1      542            540         2
4   2013     1     1      544            545        -1
5   2013     1     1      554            600        -6
6   2013     1     1      554            558        -4
7   2013     1     1      555            600        -5
8   2013     1     1      557            600        -3
9   2013     1     1      557            600        -3
10  2013     1     1      558            600        -2
```

we can see `day` is a column name. When I type:

```
jan1 <- filter (flights, month == 1, day==1)
```

I get the error message

> Error in match.arg(method) : object 'day' not found

But it is a column name. Could you help me?

Comment: A reproducible example would be nice ... but with I quick glance I would say that you need a `filter` call per column name or use a workaround with e.g. `grepl`

Comment: From which function is the `filter` coming from? Are you sure it's `dplyr`?

Comment: Suggest you restart / clear session --  it works fine for me.

Comment: The others are correct. `stats::filter(flights, month == 1, day==1)` gives this error.

Answer (score 14):

i think you may have a different package loaded that also defines `filter` because

```
 library(nycflights13)
 filter(flights, month==1, day==2)
```

works for me.

Can you explicitly use `dplyr::filter` and see if it works then ?

```
dplyr::filter(flights, month==1, day==2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tbl_df(data.frame(year = sample(2000:2017,10,replace = T),month = sample(1:12,10,replace = T),day = sample(1:31,10,replace = T)))

may3 <- filter(df,month == 5) %>% filter(day == 3)
```

or

```
may3 <- filter(df,month == 5 & day == 3)
```

Comment: The syntax in the question is valid  `filter (flights, month == 1, day==1)`